# Selecting <select> options by typing

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I have a simple dropdown (`<select>`) with the following markup:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <!-- ... -->
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <!-- ... -->
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
</select>
```

When the dropdown has focus and I type <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> (meaning key 1 first and the key 2 without the comma), `12` is selected. Same for <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd> matching `13` and so on.

However, when typing <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd> I would expect `11` to be selected, but instead `10` is.

When pressing <kbd>1</kbd> again, the selected value increases by 1 to `11`, then to `12` and so on. With this behavior I would also expect having <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> select `2` instead of `12`, no?

Is this some kind of default behavior? How can this be changed so <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd> selects `11` instead of `10`?

As pointed out by comments, this seems to be related to the browser. Chrome and Firefox show the described behavior whereas Internet Explorer and Edge are selecting `11` on <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>.

Comment: might be a default browser behaviour, what browser are you using? IE? The incrementing by 1 behaviour, could just be due to cycling down the list of everything starting with 1. So if you took out 13 for example, it probably will go 10, 11, 12, 14... when pressing 1. If it is just a browser issue, I could see putting in some superfluous JS code to create the behaviour you want.

Comment: But wouldn't this select `20` or `2` when typing `1-2`?

Comment: Seems like `IE` and `Edge` are doing what I would expect. `Chrome` instead has the described behavior. Will check what `firefox` is doing

Comment: In that case you'll probably need to add some custom Javascript if you want that exact behaviour. I'll try add an answer with some example code

Comment: I've edited your question somewhat to improve readability, hope you agree.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this behavior is [specified](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element), so it's up to the browser creator to decide how to implement it.

Chrome's default behavior seems to be what you describe:

1. Given a *repeated* keypress (<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>), the browser will *cycle* through the options that start with that particular character.
2. When the keypresses *don't* repeat (<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>), the browser will select the option that starts with the entered *sequence*.

Internet Explorer seems to favor the second behavior even with repeated keypresses, but will fall back to cycling after the first non-matching element is added to the sequence (<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd> when the last match is `11`).

```html
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>15</option>
  <option>14</option>
  <option>13</option>
  <option>12</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>20</option>
  <option>21</option>
  <option>22</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this behaviour is dependant on the browser and how they've implemented it (MS most likely wanting to match the operating systems behaviour).

If you want this exact behaviour for whatever your application needs it for (not recommended as users are probably expecting a certain behaviour that they're used to), you could try implementing some JS/jQuery like this:

```
var keyIdleTimer = null;
var consecKeys = '';

$('select').keypress(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which); //get letter of key

    //check if there's a previous letter pressed
    if (keyIdleTimer) {
        clearTimeout(keyIdleTimer);
    }

    consecKeys += key;

    $(this).val(consecKeys); //select the value

    keyIdleTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        keyIdleTimer = null;
        consecKeys = '';
    }, 500); //time required for a user to hit a second letter
});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/844umqz8/

I just tested it in Chrome, and doesn't quite work with the actual dropdown popup, but does work when the field is just in focus (with no popup), might work on IE.

Comment: Nice approach, but this breaks when the user enters a sequence that's not in the options list (like `A`, or `1`, `1`, `1`). You can fix that by checking whether `consecKeys` actually exists as a non-disabled element in the options, and if so, call `e.preventDefault()`. Otherwise, let the browser handle the event.

Comment: You're right. I've made a revision here: https://jsfiddle.net/844umqz8/1/, however I still think the original version demonstrates the logic cleaner, and it shouldn't really be used "as is" anyway, but more, adopted to what suits the application better